# IllegalArgumentException error for running a pyspark mllib example

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am following the Spark ML[example here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/ml-guide.html#example-estimator-transformer-and-param),

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.param import Param, Params

# Prepare training data from a list of (label, features) tuples.
training = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.1, 0.1])),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.0, -1.0])),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.3, 1.0])),
    (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.2, -0.5]))], ["label", "features"])

# Create a LogisticRegression instance. This instance is an Estimator.
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01)
# Print out the parameters, documentation, and any default values.
print "LogisticRegression parameters:\n" + lr.explainParams() + "\n"

# Learn a LogisticRegression model. This uses the parameters stored in lr.
model1 = lr.fit(training)
```

However,  `model1 = lr.fit(training)`  gives the following error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-3e398ce8c8bd> in <module>
      1 # Learn a LogisticRegression model. This uses the parameters stored in lr.
----> 2 model1 = lr.fit(training)

C:\spark\spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    127                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    128             else:
--> 129                 return self._fit(dataset)
    130         else:
    131             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

C:\spark\spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    319 
    320     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 321         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    322         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    323         return self._copyValues(model)

C:\spark\spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    316         """
    317         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 318         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    319 
    320     def _fit(self, dataset):

C:\spark\spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\spark\spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    132                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    133                 # JVM exception message.
--> 134                 raise_from(converted)
    135             else:
    136                 raise

C:\spark\spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in raise_from(e)

IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column features must be of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> but was actually struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>.
```

Comment: do not mix spark.ml and spark.mllib, which is known to cause this sort of errors.

Comment: @mck, could you elaborate more on your comments,  How to modify the above example? Thanks.

Comment: use Vectors from ml, not mllib